# mouseover image change with sound

Tags: javascript, css

I am working on a website and I have an image (actually a picture of a house with windows) and I want to have a face (Goldilocks) pop up in a window on mouseover along with some sound.   Ideally the face would move in during a few frames and not just appear on mouseover.  What is the best way to do this.  I am kind of new to this web design so thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4):

Without any of yours code, I can only recommend [jQuery Transit](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/) for animations (you can use pure [CSS3 animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Tutorials/Using_CSS_animations) with keyframes, or background image sprites with [CSS3 transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Tutorials/Using_CSS_transitions) on hover, but using jQuery is maybe better here to sync events). An second plugin is [jSound](http://jquer.in/jquery-plugins-to-add-multimedia-to-your-website/jsound/).

Of course, you can find many another plugins for this, you can even write your own code to play sound from HTML5 [`<audio>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/audio) tag on hover.

---

P.S. Welcome to web design brotherhood :) But Stackoverflow is not a forum. Your question is downvoted because you didn't try anything. Use Google, search, learn, try something, make some code. And then if your code don't work, ask question here and paste your code. Then we can help you and fix your code.